# Crystal Report Subreport

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report, subreport

I have this queries:

```
select idCustumer, Name, Address from Customer
```

This give me the header of the report, and this one:

```
select idCustomer, Description, Sum(Total) as Total from Product group by Description
```

First query runs:

```
 idCustomer    Name     Address
     1        Phil       Fake Av. 1234
     2        John       Fake Av. 4321
```

The second:

```
 idCustomer    Description    Sum(Total)
   1              PROD01          10
   1              PROD02          20
   2              PROD01          30
```

When i use generate a report using one customer it's ok. The problem is with 2 or more customers in the same report.

What i do?

I create 1 dataset with 2 tables (1 per query) linking them by idCustomer. I create a report using this dataset, the first table (header) works fine, it prints my four test customers.

Then i add a SubReport.

```
rpt.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(subReportes.Tables(1)) 'Tables(1) is 2nd Query
```

But this print the same info again and again.

My Report:

```
 Customer: Phil  Address: Fake Av. 1234

 Order:
              PROD01          10
              PROD02          20
              PROD01          30

              Total           60

 Customer: John  Address: Fake Av. 4321

 Order:
              PROD01          10
              PROD02          20
              PROD01          30

              Total           60
```

Is there a guide or link where i can learn how to include this subreport so i get (or if there is a another way to accomplish this?)

```
 Customer: Phil  Address: Fake Av. 1234

 Order:
              PROD01          10
              PROD02          20

              Total           30    

 Customer: John  Address: Fake Av. 4321

 Order: 
              PROD01          10

              Total           10
```

I'm using VS 2010 (VB), SQL Server 2008 R2, Crystal Report 2010

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is totally wrong. First you need to write a procedure in TSQL like this

```
SELECT C.idCustomer CustomerId, C.Name Name, C.Address Address, P.Description Description, P.Total Total
FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN PRODUCT P
   ON C.idCustumer = P.idCustomer
```

And add set this proc as the datasource for the report.
Then you have to do a grouping for field, CustomerId in the report. After that you need to place the customer details in the group header section and the order details in the Details section. And also to get the total value for the you have to use the summary field in crystal reports